# Integral Evaluation of a Fourth of a Circle

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The problem says to evaluate the integral by interpreting it in terms of areas.
$$\int_{-3}^03+\sqrt{9-x^2}\text dx$$

The function looks like a semicircle when graphed, but the problem only calls for half of that, so I used the formula $\pi\cdot r^2\over 4$, but the answer is incorrect. Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think that goind to be a square of lenght 3 and $\frac14$ of a circle of radius 3, try to drawn the figure, will help.

Comment: You're on the right track but note that the circle has been shifted vertically. There is a rectangular region of area you're neglecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.

The integral:

$$\int_{-3}^{0} \sqrt{9-x^2}dx$$

Is the area of half of a semicircle with radius $3$.

However, your integral includes:

$$\int_{-3}^{0} \sqrt{9-x^2} +3dx$$

If we split them:

$$\int_{-3}^{0} \sqrt{9-x^2}dx + \int_{-3}^{0} 3dx$$

Now we can solve this:

$$\frac{9\pi}{4} + \left[3x\right]_{-3}^{0} = \frac{9\pi}{4} + 9$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-3}^03+\sqrt{9-x^2}\text dx\\
=3\int_{-3}^0\text dx+\int_{-3}^0\sqrt{9-x^2}\text dx\\
=9+9\frac {\pi}4$$

Did you forget to separate the rectangular region out?

Comment: Yea, I was thinking I only needed the circular region for the area. Thank you for the help!